# C# SQL Server authentication string

Tags: c#, sql-server

The IT changed the SQL Server to a new Microsoft SQL Server 2017, and some apps stopped working. These apps (C#) use a connection string like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.100.101;Initial Catalog=Warehouse;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=******");
```

But the new server works with Windows authentication. I'd like to know how to change the authentication for the new SQL Server to make apps work again.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Check https://www.connectionstrings.com or simply remove the User ID and Password keys and Add _Trusted_Connection=Yes_

Comment: I tried this string, but still cannot connect to DB. Is there a way to change the authentication type from Windows Authentication to sort of network authentication, just as it was before with a username and password?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use the Integrated Security options, so the windows account that is running your C# program will be used

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.100.101;Initial Catalog=Warehouse;Integrated Security=True");
```

More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What if it's multiple users? Should all users have access to the SQL Server? What if the database has a specific login account that it uses?

Comment: I tried this string but still cannot connect to DB.